# dropzone.js file filtering and adding remove link

Tags: javascript, php, html, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone.js to upload file to server and am quite new to this; I looked for similar question and answers but I couldn't find any solution. I am using dropzone version 4.3, and I want to add cancel link to each file before uploading to remove files that are selected and a file filter for images pdf and doc files.

Here is my code

```
<form action='control/upload.php' class = "dropzone" id = 'my-dropzone"></form>
<button id ='file_sub'>upload</button>
```

js -

```
Dropzone.autodiscover = false;
Dropzone.options.my-dropzone = {
   autoProcessQueue:false,
   addRemoveLinks:true,
   acceptedFiles:".png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif,.bmp,.doc,.docx,.pdf",
   init:function(){
      this.addRemoveLink=true;
   }
};

$ ('#file_sub').click (function (){my-dropzone.processQueue});
```

But none of it is working, the files will be automatically send and any file can be uploaded and the remove link doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some misspells in your code like the first `Dropzone.autodiscover` is `Dropzone.autoDiscover` note the 'D', besides you don't need to set autoDiscover to false if you are setting the options.

And to set the options you have to call the camelized id of the html element, in this case `myDropzone` instead of `my-dropzone´, this is the main reason your script is not working, because dropzone loads with the default options. Also you need to set the event listener for uploading the files inside the init function. Here you can a look with the correct syntax:

html:

```
<form action="control/upload.php" class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone"></form>
<button id="file_sub">upload</button>
```

js:

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    autoProcessQueue:false,
    addRemoveLinks:true,
    acceptedFiles:".png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif,.bmp,.doc,.docx,.pdf",
    init: function() {
        var myDropzone = this;
        $('#file_sub').click(function(){
            myDropzone.processQueue();
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks it worked perfectly but i noticed that now it only send two files per click  i have cheacked the file size are not big and i havent set any limit on file number or size.is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @NatnaelGetachew, yeah, that is the default behaviour of dropzone. To allow the upload of more than 2 files a a time you need to add to the options the pareallel uploads limit, by default this is 2,  lets say `parallelUploads: 10`.

Comment: yes i am fine with the parallel upload limit but it wont continue to the next files that are not uploaded when the two finish uploding until i click upload again

Comment: @NatnaelGetachew, yeah, they don't continue uploading because is limited to 2, and `autoProcessQueue` is set to false hence you have to manually restart the upload by pressing the button, There are several workarounds for that but the easiest way to upload al the files at once is to increase the `parallelUploads` limit to some number bigger than the number of files you are expecting to upload, and then all will upload at once.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for Dropzone is a bit lacking in some respects. I worked through this more than a year ago, but I remember having similar issues. Here is the initialization I have on a page that does essentially what you are looking to do.

```
var previewNode = document.querySelector("#preview-template");
previewNode.id = "";
var previewTemplate = previewNode.parentNode.innerHTML;
previewNode.parentNode.removeChild(previewNode);
var acceptedFilesList = ".flv, .mp4, .jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .png, .doc, .docx, .pdf, .xls, .xlsx, .ppt, .pptx, .txt";

myDropzone = new Dropzone(document.body, {
        url: "[url to post to]",
        clickable: "[id$=dropzone-clickable]", // Make dropdown menu item clickable for uploads
        previewTemplate: previewTemplate, // Use the previewTemplate div from markup to generate html in the modal for each file added
        autoQueue: false, // Make sure the files aren't queued until manually added
        previewsContainer: "#previews", // Define the container to display the previews
        paramName: "UploadImage", // The variable name of the uploaded file on submit
        acceptedFiles: acceptedFilesList
        });
```

The previewTemplate is a set of markup which is used to display information about each file the user is trying to upload. Dropzone's documentation actually does a pretty good job of explaining the previewTemplate and how you can customize it.

I then use an event listener on "addedfile" to customize the preview row:

```
myDropzone.on("addedfile", function (file) {
    /* added logic for setting up the preview row, 
    investigate the file object within this to see what you can do */
});
```

Finally, I have a button which starts the uploads (in dropzone terms, enqueues all the files that have been added):

```
$(".btn-start-all").on("click", function () {            
    var addedFiles = myDropzone.getFilesWithStatus(Dropzone.ADDED);
    addedFiles.forEach(function (upload) {
        myDropzone.enqueueFile(upload);
    });
});
```

This is kind of a stripped down/bare bones version of what I have but hopefully it'll be a good reference for you to work through what you need